# Design patterns to recover system from intermediate state after crashing

Tags: java, soa, distributed

My system is made up of couple of components, a request typically goes through all components and each component uses own DB table to track system states.

For example, when a request arrives, component A creates a resource R by:
1. create DB row for R, marking state as "Creating"
2. application layer does the real work which may takes up to couple of minutes or hours.
3. update DB row for R, marking state as "Ready"

every component does similar things.

The problem is, the system may crash at any time and leave the system in an intermediate state. For example, resource R may remain in "Creating" after system failure.

My question is, for system like this which can not use a transaction to cover all steps(either the transaction is too long or the system is distributed), what're the design patterns or best practice to recover system?

I thought this case is very common in ERP system or any system that uses SOA.

**UPDATE:**
The request can be resent, but the resource R which is in intermediate state 'Creating' which may have been created in real world, this is somehow like in a distributed system, a component crash causes whole system states inconsistent. what's some practice to design a system that can resync system after failure?

Comment: Why would the intermediate stage take hours? Is that a real characteristic of your system?

Comment: You are saying that a conventional two phase commit would be unsuitable because of the long intermediate stage?

Comment: Sounds like queues and messaging are the best solution, but for a quick fix: if application in step 2 is single threaded, can it check for and reset any units in state "Creating" to the previous state on startup? Therefore, a startup of "application" will reset the state and start the processing again, given there were no side effects in previous step 2?

Comment: @Raedwald Yes I am saying two phase commit is not capable of because 1) each component running in different threads and communicating through message bus, transaction is hard to distributed. 2) components takes very long time to complete task. For example, copying a 2T file to remote machine.

Comment: @vikingsteve my system already uses message bus and queues. Thing is even harder because my system has multiple nodes, a starting node can not simply reset these staging state as it may be in process of other node. Actually I think amending stating state is not easy and error-prone. now I am searching a way to directly drop these staging resource and recreate a new one. however, the system is fair complex and large, I am seeking a generic pattern for this kind of stuff

Comment: Perhaps http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/TransactionalClient.html is what you are looking for? It's an Enterprise Integration Pattern (EIP)

Comment: @vikingsteve yeah, my system uses lots of patterns from EIP. But for the transactional client, it's too abstract and not easy to implement in real world.

Answer (score 2):

You can route your requests as JMS messages over the components of your system. That way you can delegate the task of message persistence and delivery guarantee to JMS implementation (eg. Active MQ). If a component crashes, the message will be redelivered to it.

Following section is added per OP's comment.

> UPDATE: The request can be resent, but the resource R which is in intermediate state   'Creating' which may have been created in real world, this is somehow like in a distributed system, a component crash causes whole system states inconsistent. what's some practice to design a system that can resync system after failure?

This is highly dependent on the nature of the system in question and its components, here is one way to accomplish failure-resistant systems.

1) Messages between components should not be lost and their delivery should be guaranteed. This can be accomplished via a dedicated message queue.

2) Each operation should be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), can be invoked more than once without any additional side effects. That way if an error occurs during the message processing, message queue will send the message again and the component will handle the message, eg. check its completion status against its local state and perform only necessary steps to complete the operation, skipping the already completed ones.

For a more complete answer and system design guides please take a look at [WS-BPEL](http://ode.apache.org/ws-bpel-20.html)

Comment: My system has used Rabbitmq as message bus, in fact every component communicates through message bus. I am familiar with these message patterns, however, my system was integrated with many thridparty vendors's product, it's impossible to make request idempotent because vendor's product is out of my control.